# Average quantity per month on a table for a specific row SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, mssql-jdbc

I have the below table:

```
        MONTHNUMBER | MonthName | ProductName | QTY | AMOUNT | AVG qty/mos|
      |-------------|-----------|-------------|-----|--------|------------|
      | 1           | January   | Thingamabob | 11  | 100.00 |            |
      | 1           | January   | Widgets     | 18  | 150.00 |            |
      | 2           | February  | Thingamabob | 10  | 100.00 |            |
      | 2           | February  | Widgets     | 6   | 150.00 |            |
      | 3           | March     | Thingamabob | 8   | 100.00 |            |
      | 3           | March     | Widgets     | 20  | 150.00 |            |
      | 4           | April     | Thingamabob | 13  | 100.00 |            |
      | 4           | April     | Widgets     | 21  | 150.00 |            |
      | 5           | May       | Thingamabob | 10  | 100.00 |            |
      | 5           | May       | Widgets     | 17  | 150.00 |            |
```

Is it possible to get the average QTY for every row's MonthName and add that to the AVG qty/mos column?

What I wanted for the table is to be like this:

```
        MONTHNUMBER | MonthName | ProductName | QTY | AMOUNT | AVG qty/mos|
      |-------------|-----------|-------------|-----|--------|------------|
      | 1           | January   | Thingamabob | 11  | 100.00 |    14.5    |
      | 1           | January   | Widgets     | 18  | 150.00 |    14.5    |
      | 2           | February  | Thingamabob | 10  | 100.00 |      8     |
      | 2           | February  | Widgets     | 6   | 150.00 |      8     |
      | 3           | March     | Thingamabob | 8   | 100.00 |     14     |
      | 3           | March     | Widgets     | 20  | 150.00 |     14     |
      | 4           | April     | Thingamabob | 13  | 100.00 |    16.5    |
      | 4           | April     | Widgets     | 21  | 150.00 |    16.5    |
      | 5           | May       | Thingamabob | 10  | 100.00 |    13.5    |
      | 5           | May       | Widgets     | 17  | 150.00 |    13.5    |
```

I've tried the below script and I would get the same result as the QTY.

```
SUM(QTY)/COUNT(DISTINCT(MonthName))
```

I hope this is possible with SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use monthname in partition as well

```
    select a.*,avg(QTY) over(partition by MonthName) as avgqty
    from tab a
```

But i think it is better to use `month and year` both should be in `partition by` because 
january month of which year it may also need of yours in future

Answer (score 4):

You could use `avg` window function to do this.

```
select t.*,avg(qty) over(partition by monthnumber) as avg_qty_per_mnth
from tbl t
```